# Reason behind the large size of meteor js apps/projects

Tags: meteor, directory

I've been cleaning up my directories and noticed that each Meteor.js project takes up at least 77MB (and typically, more like 150MB)! To figure out what was happening, I went ahead and created a new app:

```
meteor create myapp
```

At this point, the folder takes up about 7kb.
But after I do this

```
cd myapp
meteor
```

the folder size balloons up to 77MB.

After some digging around, I managed to pinpoint to size increase the `.meteor/db` folder. More specifically, running the app creates these `local*` files inside `.meteor/db` which are each >16Mbs. I opened these and they're mainly just a long string of `0000`s with a few non-`0000`s here and there. 
If I start doing more -- adding data, to `Meteor.collections`, etc -- the size balloons to 100+MB.

**My questions**

- What are these files for and why are they so huge?
- Is there any way to make my app smaller (zipping the folder cuts the size down to 1.8MB so a lot of the additional bloat looks like it  could be stripped away somehow.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Running meteor in development mode (the default) creates an instance of mongodb for you under your `.meteor` directory. It's *huge*, I know. But don't worry - this is only for development so you don't need to setup your own mongodb instance on your localhost. You can clean it up at any time by running:

```
$ meteor reset
```

When you go to deploy your app, you will bundle your project which does not include any of these files.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Is this minimongo? Also, can I just delete those local* files directly or will that mess things up?

Comment: No, it's a real instance of mongodb. Minimongo is a simplified version of mongo which runs on the client (it's what allows you to run mongo commands in your templates). I'm unclear if removing the files manually is safe, and the file layout will probably change over time, so I can't advise that.

Comment: Most of the files will be recreated once you run the meteor command again, however, you may be able to break things by removing certain combinations of files.

Answer (score 3):

To add to what [David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon) said.

If the size of the app locally is an issue, you could always use a Mongo database that is not stored locally, like a mongodb-as-a-service provider such as: [MongoLab](https://www.mongolab.com/welcome/) or [MongoHQ](http://www.mongohq.com/home)

Answer (score 0):

Also, for me using `jasmine` tests created a `mirrors` folder totaling 15Gb...