# how to recreate .meteor directory at another developer place?

Tags: meteor

I am starting out on a project that I want to work with my friend in GitHub, so I created the meteor project locally and then added it to github. It added everything except .meteor directory. When my colleague cloned and got the project down since it is missing .meteor directory, he is unable to start working on it. How do we go about recreating .meteor file at another location or am I suppose to include .meteor file into github as well? 
*** Edit: Since it is brand new project, I asked him to recreate the project locally and copy .meteor directory from the newly created one and copy it to git file location and it worked. Now sure it is the right way though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always check in your `.meteor` directory because it contains critical information like which meteor version to use and the required packages for the project.

I suspect you may have avoided doing so because of the [huge database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178363/reason-behind-the-large-size-of-meteor-js-apps-projects/) stored within that directory. Fear not - each meteor project comes with a `.meteor/.gitignore` which will avoid checking in your DB.