# How does Meteor work without installing MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have started looking at [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28platform%29) and tried out some examples, but I'm puzzled by something: I have installed Meteor and not MongoDB on my machine, but Meteor seems to create its own instance of MongoDB.

1. How does this work?
2. Am I able to develop a separate application that can also perform [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on this database that Meteor is spinning up?

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22178363/reason-behind-the-large-size-of-meteor-js-apps-projects).

Answer (score 0):

1. Meteor is shipped with a MongoDB installation
2. I think you can. The `meteor mongo` command gives the MongoDB URL to the database Meteor spins up.

Answer (score 0):

`meteor` command will start its own instance of MongoDB.

You can then use `meteor mongo` to connect to the MongoDB database, which is usually running on the application's port+1, for example, app:3000 -> mongodb@:3001. So you could use any MongoDB tool to connect (for example, robomongo).

```
$ meteor mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
```

Comment: NewB: Is the mongodb that comes with meteor any different from the original mongodb? because monogodump and mongorestore command from system shell doesn't work.